# Scroll down a webpage by constant speed

Tags: jquery

I want to create a navigation bar with links to the different sections of my website.
The website has to be a single page with the different sections under each others like Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Today I use this JQuery method to scroll down on clicking a link

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
        $(document.body).animate({
            'scrollTop':   $('#' + hash).offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

But this action takes me 2 seconds to scroll to the anchor, no matter where it is in the page. 
Is there a way to perform this action but with a chosen speed instead of a chosen time ?

Thanks,
Flow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?  You define the amount of pixels you'd like to travel per second and it adjusts the animation duration accordingly:

```
var pixels_per_second = 200;
function scrollTo(hash) {
    distance = Math.abs($(document.body).scrollTop( ) - $('#' + hash).offset( ).top);
    console.log(distance);
    scroll_duration = (distance / pixels_per_second) * 1000;
    console.log(scroll_duration);
    $(document.body).animate({ 'scrollTop':   $('#' + hash).offset().top }, scroll_duration);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qNBC6/

Comment: This solution works too and allows me to define the pace of the animation. Thank you !

Comment: for me it worked after I replaced `document.body` with `'html, body'` with the `animate` method.